# Bad robot! I just logged in, I didn't create the post in 0.35 seconds!

Tags: bug, answers, login, captcha, sign-up

### Problem

The robot dialogue (captcha) presents itself if you

1. Compose a post on a site you haven't logged into without submitting the post
2. Log in
3. Submit the post (it's already filled out since Stack Exchange kindly remembers the content of the form)
4. Be treated like a spammer because while step 1 may have taken many minutes, step 3 took less than a second, thus you must not be a real person

Please consider adding a rule to the captcha that notices if the user followed the sequence `enough time spent on an answer post` then `login/register` then `insufficient time spent on an answer post`

I know it's not trivial to fix, and it's probably rare, but it's the *right* thing to do.

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm a robot, but I'm playing by the rules.  Can we all get along?

Comment: Nice try robot.

Comment: Yes, affirmative.